# Break simplified DES

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, des

Given that theres no initial permutation only 16 32 bit long randomly generated keys and the round function is simply `f(x) = x ⊕ Ki`. Also there are 10 64bit plaintext/cyphertext pairs given.

---

Now I have to show a way to universally break this cypher, but I can only think of brute-force. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is brute-force not good enough?

Comment: I got told that brute-forcing a 512bit key would take too long and that there is another way, but I just can't think of any

Comment: Okay, so what you really want is a "computationally feasible way to universally break" the cipher.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint on one avenue of approach (actually, there are several possible):

Suppose we had two plaintexts $X$ and $X'$, which are identical except in one bit.  Now, consider $\text{SimpleDES}_K(X)$ and $\text{SimpleDES}_K(X')$; how are they related?

If that's too difficult, consider how both $\text{SimpleDES}_K(X)$ and $\text{SimpleDES}_K(X')$ are related after 1 round, after 2 rounds, etc...